# How to use GNU parallel with gunzip

Tags: bash, ls, gunzip, gnu-parallel

I have a directory full of `.gz`, I want to expand each archive in parallel with GNU parallel. However I did not achieve anything.

I tried

```
parallel 'gunzip {}' ::: `ls *.gz`
parallel gunzip `ls *.gz`
```

with no results, bash tells me:

```
/bin/bash: archive1.gz: command not found
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: GNU parallel , +1

Comment: GNU parallel isn't available on my platform. Is there a way to do this with xargs (I don't want to run more gz instances than my number of cores).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found [this](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=671798), which suggests using the `--gnu` flag:

```
parallel --gnu gunzip  ::: *gz
```

If this works, you should either delete `/etc/parallel/config` or change its contents to `--gnu` rather than `--tollef` (as root):

```
echo "--gnu" > /etc/parallel/config
```

Also, [never parse the output of `ls`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), use globbing as I have above or `find` instead:

```
find . -name "*gz*" -print0 | parallel -q0 gunzip
```

Comment: It totally works.. thanks for tips and corrections.

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is less of an issue when piping into GNU Parallel. As long as you do not have malicious users making filenames containing \n you are safe. In this case, however,  `::: *.gz` would probably be the best.

Comment: Putting \n in filenames is pretty fun indeed, thanks for the tip. However for small admin tasks it shouldn't be an issue so it's not worth taking a habit of using some other tool IMHO.

Comment: @Aki In fact it is VERY much worth making a habit of using the correct tool for the job. `ls` output changes between *nix flavors, and locale settings, it tends to break on any kind of white space, not just newlines, you willavoid a lot of pain if you get used to not parsing ls. Globbing is both simpler and safer.

Comment: @terdon: `for i in $(ls) do command "$i"; done`, I use this a lot and, globing is not always an option. Making habits < understanding the limitations of the tools I use, of course when performing sensitive tasks it's important to be careful, but space should be left for quick idioms that just work regardless of the fact they are not suitable for everything

Comment: @Aki `for i in *; do command "$i"; done` is easier to write and safer. Why would you want to learn an idiom that is harder and more risky? Try `for i in $(ls) ` in a directory that contains files with spaces in their names. Seriously, parsing `ls` is almost always not the right or easiest way to do things. If globbing is not an option, use `find`. If you insist on using `ls` at least don't use a `for` loop, this is much safer: `ls | while read i; do command "$i"; done`  at least that won't break on spaces.

Comment: @terdon: didn't think of using globing there and thanks for the while loop advice. I kept using something because I wouldn't bother to learn better, that's fixed now

Comment: @terdon : GNU parallel isn't available on my platform. Is there a way to do this with xargs (I don't want to run more gz instances than my number of cores).

Answer (score 0):

Doing this works:

```
   ls *.gz | parallel -t gunzip
```

The `-t` is optional but is useful as it shows you the commands that are executed on stderr.

I'm not sure you are doing anything wrong `:::` should work (it's meant to be equivalent) but not even the examples in the man page work for me.

Update: the `--gnu` flag makes it work as terdon said.

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work : `gzip: stdin: not in gzip format` .. Thanks anyway

Comment: Strange, works for me

Comment: Yeah it's weird.. Which platform are you using?

Comment: Debian jessie/sid (testing).  Did your files have spaces in the names?

Comment: Spaces worked as well

Comment: No they have not.. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS..